# Safari on Mac shows tabs from iPhone that I've closed long ago

Tags: macos, icloud, safari

On Safari on Mac, I have a list named "From *my name* iPhone", with iCloud tabs that I actually do not have on my iPhone. And I can't close them! When I right-click -> Close tab, it reappears after a few seconds.
[image: Screenshot of macOS Safari] - Says I have 13 opened tabs
[image: Screenshot of iPhone] - 0 opened tabs on iPhone

If I visit new websites - they are syncing correctly, they appear on all devices and I can close them from any device.

Here is what I've tried so far:

- I've updated iOS and macOS to the latest versions.
- Disabled-enabled Safari sync on iCloud on both devices.
- Disabled-enabled iCloud on both devices.
- Cleared History/Cache on both devices.
- Enabled Debug mode in macOS Safari and tried syncing with iCloud manually.
- Tried opening those tabs on the iPhone and closing them - no luck. The newly opened tab appears along with others and clothes correctly, but the old ones stick.

I have no idea what to do next. It's been almost a year since I'm battling this behavior. Maybe the Internet can help.

Comment: I get the same problem where my iPad shows tabs I closed on my Mac long ago.